# How to set up URL masking on gh-pages and GoDaddy

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewriting, godaddy, github

I have a domain that currently redirects `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

It is hosted on `gh-pages`.

However, there is a resource link I access from index.html called privacy.html via `<a href=privacy.html>Privacy Policy<a>`.

When the user clicks that link, he/she gets redirected to `example.com/privacy.html` rather than `example.com/privacy`.

How do I set this up so it doesn't have any `.html` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you host your site on github pages and you want to access your file name without extension, then make sure your index.html page is hosted on parent directory/folder.

For example. for privacy page, host your index.html like this

```
/privacy/index.html
```

This page can accessible in browser with - `/privacy/` also with `/privacy/index.html`